# Received TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Tags: python, pandas

I recieved the TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found. I am trying to create a new dataframe from an old one.

```
set1Load = pd.read_csv("Sys 1 Settings.csv", sep =' ', header=None, dtype=str)
x,y = set1Load.shape
set1Formatted = pd.DataFrame(set1Load.values.reshape(x*y//2, 2)[:, ::-1]).apply(''.join, axis=1)
print(set1Formatted)
```

Here is a small excerpt of data from the file for reference

```
12 00 0E 00 57 23
57 23 02 23 57 0A
2D 16 0C 5A 2D 16
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error as I previously thought I set the dtype as str. Th Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have `NaN` values in the input csv?

Comment: I don't believe so, its just multiple lines of values similar to the ones listed above

Comment: Do `pd.read_csv("Sys 1 Settings.csv", sep =' ')` and then check if any of the values in the resultant DataFrame is `float`/`NaN`

Comment: Try add `astype(str)` before `apply`?

Comment: @HenryYik that worked thank you